# Using ArcGIS Pro arcade labeling profile, how to check existence of a field

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, arcgis-portal, arcade

I am trying to consolidate dozens of arcade label expressions into a single expression that is sophisticated enough to handle two different possible data sources (These expressions are being written and utilized in Pro, but also will need to work once published to Portal).   One of the data sources has additional fields that are ideal for labeling, and the other does not.  *Currently the expression fails when it declares variable for a field that does not exist*.  I have tried using multiple functions and methods to conditionally test for existence of these fields, but so far it always turns out that they are not available in the arcade labeling profile.
Examples include using "Haskey" (the variable "field_typeassetnum" references a text field name)

```
var assettype = 'sysvalve'
var field_typeassetnum = assettype + '_assetnum'

if(Haskey($feature, field_typeassetnum)){
    var typeassetnum = $feature[field_typeassetnum]
}
else
{
    var typeassetnum = ''
}
```

This method fails because the label renderer does not load all fields into the "attribute" dictionary for $feature (for my feature classes it only loads OBJECTID and GUID fields).  I tried using `Expects()` to force-load all possible fields, but that method is not available in the arcade label profile.

Another possibility was using `Domain()` methods, but those are also not available in the arcade label profile.

My core question is how to conditionally test for existence of a field in the arcade label profile.